# Rollup Opportunity fields on Custom object

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, master-detail, roll-up-summary

I have custom object that is between Account and Opportunity. I need it to roll up some of the field from the opportunity, but I can't because the opportunity cannot have another master, and rollups don't work unless something is the master.

Workflows can't call that information.

Is there a way to do this without writing code?

Comment: Alternative question. Could I perhaps create different opportunity record types, one which functions normally, and another which functions as my custom object, which would roll up the first record type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done using code but there are a couple of tools available as managed packages on AppExchange that provide roll-up summary-like functionality on lookups. Both provide a declarative UI  so you don't need to actually *write* the code.

- [Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) is free for up to three rollups
- [Declarative Rollups for Lookups](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) is free but has some limitations and known issues

Comment: I've been using Declarative Rollups for Lookups since I asked this question and have found it does everything I need it to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not.

And for your next question: "Well then how can I do it with code?"

This link is one of the best examples of how to successfully accomplish this:

http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/